# Is it possible to power a car with chemiluminescence?

Tags: visible-light, physical-chemistry, photoelectric-effect, solar-cells

[Chemiluminescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemiluminescence) means substances that in a reaction emit light.

I wonder if such a reaction would be possible to power an electric car using an photovoltaic panel lighted by the chemical reaction?

Comment: This seems to be one of the least efficient means of powering a car that I can thing of (well, something that runs on proton decay would be worse).

Answer (score 2):

An electric car needs a minimum of about 10 kW power.

Light from Chemiluminescence is quite weak compared to sunlight, so to be very optimistic I'll use the [solar constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant) ( $1.362\,kWm^{-2}$ ) as the power per unit area available to the photovoltaic cells.  Note when you see photos of Chemiluminescence you'll typically see the images taken in completely dark rooms - i.e. no other light source to hide the effect.  This is low intensity light.

Even with this source and near perfect efficiency you'd need something like $7.5\,m^2$ of panel to get enough power to match a (low powered) electric car model.

So I would say that this is very unlikely to be practical.  A specially designed ultra-lightweight vehicle (which would not be remotely practical) might possible manage it at a low speed, but I'd be very surprised.

For some perspective, an electric bicycle (i.e. a bicycle powered by a small electric motor) might have a 200 Watt engine at minimum.  Remember the light source is low intensity and you just won't get enough power.

Note that [solar powered cars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_car) do exist.  These are impressive but read the small print, as they say, as the headline figures can rely on augmentation by battery power.

Comment: The research in the chemilunescence domain has said all it could or is there enough room for improvement?

Comment: maibe with a second harmonic generation would work?

Comment: if we add something like sum frequency generation to the project would get more energy?

Comment: @user38657 You can't get more energy doing that because energy is conserved.

Comment: Yes but it depend on the material that is used as a photoovoltaic cell. Thus increasing chances of electron scattering from orbital.

Answer (score 1):

Possible? Possibly. Practically? Certainly not.

You have too many steps between the original energy form (Chemical Potential Energy) and the final, desired form (Kinetic Energy in the car). At each transition there is a loss factor (efficiency). It goes something like this:

- Chemical process produces light ($\eta_c$)
- Fraction of light incident on photovoltaics ($\eta_f$)
- Conversion to electricity ($\eta_p$)
- Electric motor efficiency ($\eta_m$)

So your overall efficiency is $\eta = \eta_c  \eta_f  \eta_p  \eta_m$

If you plug in some real-world efficiencies (between 10-30%), you get an overall efficiency of much less than 1%.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, there's no reason why not. That process can produce electricity, so it could power an electric device.

There's a major problem with scale, though. Even a small electric car has a $15~\rm kW$ engine. To put that in perspective, the average solar panel installation for a *house* produces only $6~\rm kW$, and that covers most of the roof of a house.